# T-SQL Query to remove duplicate records in the output based on one particular column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, duplicates, having

I am running SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
 USE MYDATABASE

 SELECT * 
 FROM RESERVATIONLIST
 WHERE [MTH] IN ('JANUARY 2015','FEBRUARY 2015')
```

`RESERVATIONLIST` mentioned in the code above is a view. The query gives me the following output (extract):

```
ID     NAME       DOA         DOD       Nights Spent       MTH
--------------------------------------------------------------------
251    AH     2015-01-12   2015-01-15      3           JANUARY 2015
258    JV     2015-01-28   2015-02-03      4           JANUARY 2015
258    JV     2015-01-28   2015-02-03      2           FEBRUARY 2015
```

The above output consist of around 12,000 records.

I need to modify my query so that it eliminates all duplicate ID and give me the following results:

```
 ID    NAME       DOA          DOD       Nights Spent       MTH
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 251     AH     2015-01-12   2015-01-15      3           JANUARY 2015
 258     JV     2015-01-28   2015-02-03      4           JANUARY 2015
```

I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
USE MYDATABASE

SELECT * 
FROM RESERVATIONLIST
WHERE [MTH] IN ('JANUARY 2015', 'FEBRUARY 2015')    
GROUP BY [ID] 
HAVING COUNT ([MTH]) > 1
```

Comment: what is your logic for selecting the row with `'JANUARY 2015'` and not `'FEBRUARY 2015'` for `ID = 258`

Comment: No specific logic. I just want the query to output either one of them.

Comment: You may so if you like. However the data in the result will have no real-world meaning. It would be a good suggestion to either remove the columns from the result, or aggregate them with `sum[nights spent], min(mth) as first, max(mth) as last`. In the first situation the answer will be close to deepak pawars answer, otherwise you better use a GROUP BY statement to roll-up the totals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following query will return one row per ID :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn FROM RESERVATIONLIST
    WHERE [MTH] IN ('JANUARY 2015','FEBRUARY 2015')
) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note : this will return a random row from multiple rows having same ID. IF you want to select some specific row then you have to define it in `order by`. For e.g. :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DOA DESC) rn FROM RESERVATIONLIST
    WHERE [MTH] IN ('JANUARY 2015','FEBRUARY 2015')
) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

definitely, it will return the row having `max(DOA)`.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I needed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a GROUP BY statement which IMHO is the right way to go. You should formulate all columns that are a constant, and roll-up the others. Depending on the value of DOD and DOA I can see two solutions:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,DOA,DOD,SUM([Nights Spent]) as Nights,
   min(MTH) as firstRes, max(MTH) as lastRes
FROM RESERVATIONLIST
GROUP BY ID,NAME,DOA,DOD
```

OR

```
SELECT ID,NAME,min(DOA) as firstDOA,max(DOD) as lastDOD,SUM([Nights Spent]) as Nights,
   min(MTH) as firstRes, max(MTH) as lastRes
FROM RESERVATIONLIST
GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this one a try too!

Comment: I did not get the same number of rows in the result window, compared to Deepak Pawar's solution. I will need to look deeper to find out why.